# How can I transfer data from one funtction to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to transfer data received from one function (reading) to another (writing). 
Existing data inside file.txt should be transfer into json format and be printed to the console, that data should be taken and be written on the file called pfile.txt, by the second function.
I just can't get them to work together. When running each function separately as commands in plain shell, they work; combined, not so much. What am I missing here?

```
def reading():
    filename = 'file.txt'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        print(json.loads(f.read()))
    reading()


def writing():

    with open('pfile.txt', 'w+') as pf:
      pf.write(reading() in writing())  <-- this doesn't work
      pf.write('hello SO') <-- this does work
    writing()
```

Comment: You need to learn that functions can `return` a value.  I recommend you read the official python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: It's true, editing and downvoting takes much less time than answering.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Mermelstein , Im on it!

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's completely unclear what data you're trying to pass from where to where.

Comment: @Aran-Fey not sure if you are cynical or not, but I expended my explanation to the issue I am experiencing in any case.

Comment: Are you trying to recursively call `reading()` forever? That's what it looks like you're doing.  I imagine you want that call to `reading()` to be `writing()` instead

Comment: Well, as stated earlier before I was bluntly edited, I am quite new to this field.. I have much to learn. I do appreciate any pointer given so far (and in the future)

Comment: This might help: [Calling a variable from one function to another function in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/20768856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to a function with a pair of parenthesis, Python will call that function with no arguments and resolve it's return value (if any).  This is not bash; functions pass data to each other as variables in memory, not through stdin/stdout.

Your code as written appears to be riddled with infinite loops (functions calling themselves) and likely will crash with "recursion depth exceeded" errors.  These can be fixed by not calling functions within themselves (or having cycles of functions that call each other).

There's nothing about your code as written that needs multiple functions.  I'd go down to 1 function:

```
def read_and_write():
    filename = 'file.txt'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        content = json.loads(f.read())
        print(content)
    with open('pfile.txt', 'w+') as pf:
        pf.write(content)
```

If you want two functions, try the following:

```
def read():
    filename = 'file.txt'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        content = json.loads(f.read())
        return content

def write():
    content = read()
    with open('pfile.txt', 'w+') as pf:
        pf.write(content)
```

Comment: I get it now, I saw a reference about using  content = read()  for the second function, but without the return part. going to test it out now (-: Thanks for the example.